# T SQL - How can I get some data from a field or column in SQL table

Tags: t-sql

I need to get some data from a column.

For example I have data in a column like peter@msn.com. I want to get msn.com.

How I can I get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(100) = 'peter@msn.com'
SELECT RIGHT(@a, LEN(@a) - CHARINDEX('@', @a))
```

Comment: Just be aware that if you use a function on a column that prevents sql server from using indexes.  So if you try to find all the @msn.com email addresses you'll be looking at a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Columnname,7,LEN(Columnname));
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I want generic @ sign, Not 7 as a constant number.